# MobileFirst SQL Adapters requestTimeoutInSeconds

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters, worklight-studio

I have WL6.0 project that contains SQL adapter. The adapter has procedure with `requestTimeoutInSeconds="240"` and I am trying to migrate that project to WL7.1.
As per `Adapter timeout and concurrency` article on IBM Knowledge Center, I have to use JNDI config instead.

> The requestTimeoutInSeconds attribute of  and
>    elements is ignored. Use JNDI configuration instead.

Can any one provide an example how to implement that?

I am working on MobileFirst Studio 7.1 and I imported the project with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are developing in MobileFirst Studio, which utilizes the Liberty application server as its underlying server.

Locally such changes are not required, since you're working locally...
This will become important once you start on moving to testing and production environments.

This means that you will need to update the server.xml of your WebSpher full profile/Liberty profile - not the server.xml of the server in MobileFist Studio.

You you can find documentation for this in the Liberty docs, here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html

Note that the setup you need to do differs based on your database type: MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ... You can find examples for each database type in the link above.